# Received start of new message but previous message is unfinished

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

My web based WebSocket client connects to my Java server this way:

```
this.ws = new WebSocket(this.url);
  this.ws.onmessage = m => {
    let data;
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(m.data);
    } catch (e) {
      // Log error
      return;
    }
    doALotOfStuff(data);
  };
```

But then sometimes I get this error in Chrome:

> WebSocket connection to 'myServerUrl' failed: Received start of new
>   message but previous message is unfinished.

I found the [related source code in Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/lkgr/net/websockets/websocket_channel.cc) and some discussion about it but this is all about continuation frames and OpCode, a much lower API than the one I have access to from what I understood.

So does this mean I received a message while I was processing the previous one? Meaning I have to call setTimeout(...,0) to handle all my messages asynchronously? But then everybody should do it so why does the browser not handle this?

I have a similar error in Firefox:

> The connection to myServerUrl was interrupted while the page was loading.

Which is more confusing I guess because I am not reloading a page, it happens in the middle of a websocket session.

So I guess it might not be Chromium fault but then how do I handle it?

Or am I doing something wrong when sending the messages? I use javax-websocket-api-1.0 and I simply do:

```
try (Writer writer = session.getBasicRemote().getSendWriter()) {
  JacksonSerializer.serialize(object, writer);
} catch (final SerializerException | IOException e) {
  throw ...;
}
```

I close the writer everytime I write an object in it so this looks fine to me.

Comment: This sounds like a problem on the server with how the messages are being sent where the webSocket protocol is being violated (unfinished message frame), either an issue with the Java webSocket library or an issue with how  you are using it.

Comment: Looks like the problem is, your server is setting the `FIN` bit to false. So the client is expecting the next data-frame to have the `opcode` set to `continuation`, but this is not happening, and hence the error. see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Message_Fragmentation

Comment: I looked more precisely at the server code thanks to your inputs and found the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed due to a bug in the server code. The code I quoted is correct but was not thread-safe so I wrote concurrently into the same session. I fixed it by synchronizing it on the session.